# TabControl transparent background

Tags: user-interface, background, tabcontrol, transparent

I'd like to know if there's some way to render the background of a TabControl transparent (the TabControl, not the TabPages), instead of taking the parent form background color. I've some forms with custom painting where I draw a gradient as the background but this gradient doesn't paint behind the tabcontrols. I tried setting TabControl.Backcolor = Color.Transparent but it tells me it's not supported. I'm using VS2005 and framework 2.0.
(set style does not help)
Does anyone have good workaround to this issue?

Answer (score 3):

custom tab conrol:

```
[DllImport("uxtheme", ExactSpelling = true)]
public extern static Int32 DrawThemeParentBackground(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hdc, ref Rectangle pRect);

protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.BackColor == Color.Transparent)
    {
        IntPtr hdc = e.Graphics.GetHdc();
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(e.ClipRectangle.Left,
            e.ClipRectangle.Top, e.ClipRectangle.Width, e.ClipRectangle.Height);
        DrawThemeParentBackground(this.Handle, hdc, ref rec);
        e.Graphics.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
    }
    else
    {
        base.OnPaintBackground(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have removed the if/else statement from your original code as TabControl did not appear to have a BackColor property, even though it has an OnBackColorChanged event

Comment: it has, but you have to make a `custom tab control`. However, i tried to make         `[Browsable(true)]
        public new Color BackColor
        {
            get { return base.BackColor; }
            set { base.BackColor = value; }
        }`, but for some reasons I can't change `BackColor` of my `TabControl`, it always stuck at `SystemColors.Control`, so it looks like this `if` indeed doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Sinatr, `BackColor` is overridden in `TabControl`, and always returns `SystemColors.Control`. I guess you already figured, given your answer below.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread on msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/7c6ec2ca-9f58-4a01-b309-c4fb6cffc704), the tabcontrol does not support changing the backcolor to transparent, however you can supposedly override the drawitem method.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to extend answer of `Golan` (as he is inactive?)

You can use [DrawThemeParentBackground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773306%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to do most of job. Create custom TabControl:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Code")]
public class MyTabControl : TabControl
{

    [DllImport("uxtheme", ExactSpelling = true)]
    public extern static Int32 DrawThemeParentBackground(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hdc, ref Rectangle pRect);

    // use with care, as it may cause strange effects
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;  // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
            return cp;
        }
    } 

    public MyTabControl() { }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr hdc = e.Graphics.GetHdc();
        Rectangle rect = ClientRectangle;
        DrawThemeParentBackground(this.Handle, hdc, ref rect);
        e.Graphics.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
    }
}
```

and set explicitly for every `TabPage` `BackColor=Transparent` (in Designer or during run-time, if you don't - `TabPage`'s will have white background). Works like a miracle, transparent flicker-free TabControl which I was dreaming for.

Comment: You actually have to explicitly set BackColor of the tab pages to Transparent, even if it already says so in the designer. Alternatively, you can override `OnCreateControl()`, and loop through the TabPages collection, setting `BackColor` to `Color.Transparent`.

Comment: Yes, `explicitly` is the right word, thanks. Another thing, be careful with `CreateParams` (possibly delete it completely), because it may cause strange issues. This would return flickering back though ><

Answer (score 1):

As [explained on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabpage.usevisualstylebackcolor(v=vs.110).aspx), you should

- Check if `Application.RenderWithVisualStyles` returns true
- Have the TabPage's `UseVisualStyleBackColor` property set to true
- Have the TabControl `Appearance` property set to `Normal`

then your TabPage should have a transparent background.